# python subprocess with ffmpeg give no output

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I m want to extract the scene change timestamp using the scene change detection from ffmpeg. I have to run it on a few hundreds of videos , so i wanted to use a python subprocess to loop over all the content of a folder.
My problem is that the command that i was using for getting these values on a single video involve piping the output to a file which seems to not be an option from inside a subprocess call.

this is my code :

```
 p=subprocess.check_output(["ffmpeg", "-i", sourcedir+"/"+name+".mpg","-filter:v", "select='gt(scene,0.4)',showinfo\"","-f","null","-","2>","output"])
```

this one tell ffmpeg need an output

```
 output = "./result/"+name
 p=subprocess.check_output(["ffmpeg", "-i", sourcedir+"/"+name+".mpg","-filter:v", "select='gt(scene,0.4)',metadata=print:file=output","-an","-f","null","-"])
```

this one give me no error but doesn't create the file

this is the original command that i use directly with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv  -filter:v "select='gt(scene,0.4)',showinfo"  -f null  - 2> ffout
```

I just need the ouput of this command to be written to a file, anyone see how i could make it work?
is there a better way then subprocess ? or just another way ? will it be easier in C?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the `stderr` output directly from Python without any need for `shell=True` which can lead to shell injection.

It's as simple as:

```
with open(output_path, 'w') as f:
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, stderr=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Things are easier in your case if you use  the `shell` argument of the `subprocess` command and it should behave the same. When using the shell command, you can pass in a **string** as the command rather then a **list of args.**

```
cmd = "ffmpeg -i {0}  -filter:v \"select='gt(scene,0.4)',showinfo\"  -f {1}  - 2> ffout".format(inputName, outputFile)
p=subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
```

If you want to pass arguments, you can easily format your string

Comment: `shell=True` is discouraged as it can lead to shell injection.

Comment: thanks you sir , this is working but i still have the problem of passing the name of each files and change the output name for each too. If i put everything in a string and pass the string it should work no ?

for the shell injection this is a simple utility for sorting videos , atm it s not really important, we just need to show the method is working but thank you for the input at least i can tell them that in this state they may be a risk.

Comment: I've kind of expected that you knew how to do string formatting, i've added an example, how you would customize it.